What company made this stovetop espresso maker?
I'd like to get a replacement filter seal (red rubber ring) direct from the manufacturer of my stovetop espresso/steamer maker if possible. I don't know the manufacturer but, the bottom of the pot has something like a logo and says made in Italy. I've searched the internet (italian logos, italian makers, italian cookware, etc) and haven't found any companies with a logo like that.
Photo of my espresso/steamer

The rubber seal is circled

The bottom of the pot - looks like a logo in the center?

Thanks!

This looks like a Guido Bergna Stovetop Espresso Maker. I have found one article on ebay  that looks almost identical to the one in the pictures - even the logo matches. However, I have found a different product, made by Caffe Portofino that shares the same logo, but looks a bit different from underneath. Also this listing, Caffe Portofino again, looks almost identical to the one you posted.
Perhaps the logo at the bottom of the espresso maker is some sort of marking describing the material used (like the Inox marking above it).
